# Diagonal slices staggered effect using swiperjs and animejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js, animejs

I'm trying to recreate a sliding effect I saw on [supercrowds website](https://supercrowds.co) (if you wait a bit after the slogan, the image moves).

A good starting point would be using SwiperJS for the slider, and tweak the animation using css or since it looks staggered and more complex, using anime JS, as I know it has the support for that.

Does anyone know how to create a similar effect?

Answer (score 0):

There's a very similar effect now available on Swipers website:

https://uiinitiative.com/catalog/shutters-slider

It requires you to become a patron for $10, quite a reasonable price considering the amount of time it'd take you to figure out something like this!